# How to represent exponents in a 6502 assembly calculator?

Tags: assembly, 6502

I'm assigned to make a simple calculator in 6502 but can't the correct output for any attempt I make at implementing exponents (^)

```
    org 0200h
    
Main: 

    ldx #FirstNumberMessage<
    ldy #FirstNumberMessage>
    jsr 0E00Ch
    jsr 0E009h
    cmp #'q'
    beq ExitProgram
    cmp #'Q'
    beq ExitProgram
    jsr 0E015h
    sta num1
    
    ldx #OperatorMessage<
    ldy #OperatorMessage>
    jsr 0E00Ch
    jsr 0E009h
    sta operator
    
    ldx #SecondNumberMessage<
    ldy #SecondNumberMessage>
    jsr 0E00Ch
    jsr 0E009h
    jsr 0E015h
    sta Num2
    
    lda operator
    cmp #'+'
    bne CheckSubtraction
    jsr Addition
    jmp Done

CheckSubtraction:

    cmp #'-'
    bne CheckMultiplication
    jsr Subtraction
    jmp Done
   
CheckMultiplication:

    cmp #'*'
    bne ExitProgram
    jsr Multiplication
    jmp Done
    
Done:

    ldx #ResultMessage<
    ldy #ResultMessage>
    jsr 0E00Ch
    lda result
    jsr 0E012h
    lda #0ah
    jsr 0E003h
    lda #0dh
    jsr 0E003h
    
    jmp Main
    
ExitProgram:

    brk
    
Addition:

    pha 
    lda num1
    clc
    adc num2
    sta result
    pla 
    rts
    
Subtraction:

    pha 
    lda num1
    sec 
    sbc num2
    sta result
    pla
    rts
    
Multiplication:

    pha 
    lda num1
    cmp #0d
    bne Num1NotZero
    lda #0d
    sta result
    jmp ExitMultiplication
    
Num1NotZero:

    lda num2
    cmp #0d
    bne Num2NotZero
    lda #0d
    sta result
    jmp ExitMultiplication
    
Num2NotZero:

    lda num1
    sta result
    dec num2
    beq ExitMultiplication
    
Loop:

    clc
    adc num1
    dec num2
    bne Loop
    sta result
    
ExitMultiplication:

    pla
    rts
    
FirstNumberMessage:

    dbt 0ah,0dh
    dbt "Enter the first digit (press 'q' to quit): "
    dbt 0d
    
OperatorMessage:

    dbt 0ah,0dh
    dbt "Enter the operator: "
    dbt 0d
    
SecondNumberMessage:

    dbt 0ah,0dh
    dbt "Enter the second digit: "
    dbt 0d
    
ResultMessage:

    dbt 0ah,0dh
    dbt "The result is: "
    dbt 0d
    
num1: dbt ?
operator: dbt ?
num2: dbt ?
result: dbt ?

    end
```

That's my full program for reference, but since we're dealing with exponents, I'm assuming the main focus of this will be multiplication.

```
Multiplication:
    
    pha 
    lda num1
    cmp #0d
    bne Num1NotZero
    lda #0d
    sta result
    jmp ExitMultiplication
    
Num1NotZero:

    lda num2
    cmp #0d
    bne Num2NotZero
    lda #0d
    sta result
    jmp ExitMultiplication
    
Num2NotZero:

    lda num1
    sta result
    dec num2
    beq ExitMultiplication
    
Loop:

    clc
    adc num1
    dec num2
    bne Loop
    sta result
    
ExitMultiplication:

    pla
    rts
```

I'm assuming I move the result back to num1 and leave the other in a loop and have that repeat however high the exponent is, but my problem is that I don't know how to translate that into 6502.

Comment: Multiplication can be done with repeated addition, just as exponentiation can be done with repeated multiplication.  So if you have a working multiply function, you can call it in a loop.  You might need separate storage for the outer-loop counter if multiply destroys its inputs.

Comment: Binary shifted multiplication is better but the same principal applies.

Comment: An efficient method of performing multiplication in 6502 assembly is to use the "Russian Peasant Method." It is very easy to implement with bit-shifts and addition. Considering you are calculating exponents, this would be much faster than repeated addition.